# Can't access the configuration manager from my solution

Tags: c#, web-config, connection-string

I have a three tier set-up. Someone suggested I should get the ConnectionString from the Web.Config file and I've got it set up like this:

[image]

Now I'm trying to access the ConnectionString from my DAL tier, but I can't find the ConfigurationManager. How can I invoke my Connection string from here?:

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Configuration`, then have a using class for `System.Configuration`, then you will have access to:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
```

And yours can be accessed via

```
string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: I guess I meant a "using statement", i.e. `using System.Configuration`.

Answer (score 3):

1. You have to add a reference to the `System.Configuration.dll`
2. then add `using System.Configuration;` to your class.
3. You can now access your config file like this:

   `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;`